# get a view from previous activity

Tags: android

I am doing a quiz app in which there are Act1 and Act2. Act1 shows the view for each question answers to select.

```
 public class ACT1 extends Activity 
{
 EditText question=null;
  RadioGroup choices = null;
 -------
 ------
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.question);

            /* //---get the Bundle object passed in---    
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    //---get the data using the getInt() method---     
    int qId = bundle.getInt("questionIndex");
```

//dont know what to do here

```
             question = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.question);
           RadioGroup questionLayout = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.answers);

 ------

    this.getQuestionView(questionNo);
    FrameLayout quizLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.quizLayout);
    quizLayout.setVisibility(android.view.View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

and in the method getQuestionView() the rest of code for getting questions and answers next  submit buttons everything is there.

```
private void getQuestionView(questionNo)
   {
   ------
   ------
  //next and previous buttons OnClicklisteners
   ------
   private OnClickListener finishListener = new OnClickListener() 
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Act1.this,Act2.class);
           }
    }
```

And Act2 shows a view for results which includes a table for questionlinks. on clicking the question link the respective question view shall be shown which is from Act1 and on back button clicked it goes back to Act2. i am new to android so anybody please help.
        public class Act2 extends Activity {
    --------
     -------
    TableLayout questionsTable;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.result);


    int totalQues = Act1.getQuestions().length;
    questionsTable =(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.questions);
    -------
            -------     
    for(int i=0;i<totalQues;i++)
    {
        ------
                  --------

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);

        TextView queText = new TextView(this);
               tr.addView(queText,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        tr.setClickable(true);
        tr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent  intent = new Intent(this,Act1.class);
                 //---use a Bundle object to add new key/values pairs---         
                Bundle extras = new Bundle(); 
                            //here i wanna check whether 2nd question is displaying     
                extras.putInt("questionIndex",2 );                
                //---attach the Bundle object to the Intent object---       
                intent.putExtras(extras); 
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: onClick of table row get its id and then u can that particular question again

Comment: Even i can get the id dont how to get the whole view from the previous activity.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, you need is to pass some data from one activity to another. This is done through the `Intent` class, it can contain "extras" which are actually simply key-value pairs which can be written by the calling activity and later read by the called activity.

For example, I can write the code like this:

```
public static final String EXTRA_QUESTION = "question";

// When you need to create the intent:
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Act2.class);
// questionId is whatever identifies the question in your code
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_QUESTION, questionId);
```

And in the other activity you write:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
// In this example questionId is int, but it could be something else
int questionId = intent.getIntExtra(Act1.EXTRA_QUESTION, 0);
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply but can i directly pass this id to the getQuestionView () method while calling it?